# DSolve not able to solve for plane-wave solution

Tags: differential-equations

I have the input:

```
pde = D[D[f[x,y,z],x],x]+D[D[f[x,y,z],y],y]+D[D[f[x,y,z],z],z]+(k^2) f[x,y,z];
DSolve[pde==0,f[x,y,z],{x,y,z}]
```

Which then gives no answer and only returns the input again. But this has a straightforward plane-wave solution. Why can't it solve it?

Comment: Yes, it can't solve because you have `f` on the RHS. Any unknown function on RHS, it will also not solve it.  May be in Version 14 it will? But it can solve it if you replace the RHS with known function of one variable, such as `x` or `Sin[x]` or `10` etc.. inhomogeneous pde's are much harder to solve analytically than homogeneous ones. Btw, you can write the pde more easily as follows : `pde = Laplacian[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + k^2*f[x, y, z] == 0`

Comment: @Nasser But f is not on the RHS. Only 0 is.

Comment: No, Your pde has the form `LAPLACIAN(f(x,y,z)) = -k^2*f(x,y,z)` it is therefore Helmholtz pde. Not pure  Laplacian. Much harder to solve. Mathematica can solve `LAPLACIAN(f(x,y,z)) = zero, or very easy one here` with no problem.  Just because you wrote it as `LAPLACIAN(f) + f = 0` does not make any difference.

Comment: btw, there is a website that lists all versions of pde's solved by Mathematica, and it shows Mathematica is able to solve Helmholtz pde in 2D. But not in 3D.

Comment: Oh I see. But this has such a simple solution that I feel it should get it. It's just a plane-wave solution: f0 Exp[I (k/3^(1/2))(x+y+z)]

Comment: @Nasser I tried the 2D and it worked. Weird

Comment: That's one possible solution.  But Mathematica will try to find the most general possible solution consistent with the conditions you've provided, which in this case would be a completely general solution to the Helmholtz equation, which is no easy task.  If you really want to get a particular solution, you can add boundary conditions that would limit the range of possible solutions (`f[0,y,z] == f0 Exp[I (k/3^(1/2)) (y + z)`, for example.)